# SQL select - Get all from exams table where examId exists in subjects table, for all subjects that exist in students table for desired studentId

Tags: sql, select, multiple-tables

I have three tables: `exams, subjects and students`.
`Students` table has foreign key `subjectId` and `Subjects` table has foreign key `examId`.
I need to retrieve all exams for desired `studentId`. So I need sql select that will pick up all subjects for that `studentId`, and pick up all exams for all these subjects.

So pseudo code is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM exams
WHERE id IN (SELECT examId FROM subjects
             WHERE id IN (SELECT subjectId from students
                          where id === desiredId))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using subqueries and just not inner join?

Try with this:

```
Select X.* From exams X
Inner join subjects S on S.examId = X.id
Inner join students T on T.subjectId = s.Id
Where T.id =@yourStudentId
```